# Run Azure SQL Server Stored procedure async

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I am moving from an onprem SQL Server managed instance to a Azure SQL Database. My issue is that given the lack of a Sql Agent I am forced to run a Azure Function to automate some stored procedures that we`re running.

Here is the issue:

1. Azure Function cannot run more than 10 minutes (without a big hassle) my archiving job runs for about 40 minutes.
2. `sp_start_job` - does not exist in Azure SQL
3. Trying to find a way to not keep open the connection from Azure function.

Thanks in advance all help is appreciated

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/job-automation-overview

Comment: https://www.netwoven.com/2017/12/12/schedule-execution-sql-jobs-azure-automation-service/

Comment: Have you looked into using a Logic App? Also, a Web App Web Job can be scheduled. Also, a Database Job...

Comment: Do you think about Data factory [store procedure active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure)?

Comment: Hello John, which workaround would you prefer?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. If you got any progresses, can you post it as answer or share with us?

Comment: @LeonYue I have a limitation of using SQL related stuff, I cannot add anything else in the mix. So no Elastic Pool and no Data Factory :(

Answer (score 0):

I think You could using Data Factory to help you schedule execute the stored procedures.

1. Create a pipeline with on or more [Stored Procedure activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure):

[image]

Add [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers) to schedule the pipeline running:
[image]

And @Chetan Ranpariya also provided the good suggestions for you. Ref:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/job-automation-overview
2. https://www.netwoven.com/2017/12/12/schedule-execution-sql-jobs-azure-automation-service/

Hope this helps.